# How to ensure that two transactions have the same version of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have a table with columns A and B. Let's assume both are booleans. These columns will be accessed by functions in some program's code.

One function will first read A and if it is true, it will modify B(set it to false).

The second function will first read B and if it is of certain value(e.g. true), it will modify A(set it to false).

The functions might run in any order.

The problem I have is that both of these are kind of depending on each other(if second function reads that B is true, it will set A to false), which can lead to incorrect state of the database(A being false and B being false).

Ideally, I would make the function that triggers second wait until the first one is done with the rows, and then start working. However, from what I've looked up, it looks like none of the 3 protection levels will forbid the function from reading the row, only make it wait until write.

One of scenarios that I want to avoid is:

Function1 starts. It reads A(true). The function2 starts now and reads B(true). The function1 sets B to false. The function2 sets A to false. I am left with 2 false, which should not happen.

The correct scenario might look like this:
Function 1 starts. It reads A(true). The function2 starts, but has to wait for function1 to finish. Function1 sets B to false. The function2 can now access B and sees that it's false, and stops/signals error.

Can I somehow make this work using database mechanisms?

Comment: You need isolated transactions.  The place to start is with the documentation on isolation levels:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I looked at isolation levels, but it looks like I can't prevent other function from reading until I'm finished - or can I?

Comment: This problem is many process access the same resource at one time. You must use some algrithm like semaphore to ensure only one process can access to read/modify resource and one time and when the First complete, the second can go to access resource.

Comment: Perhaps you need `Application Lock` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql

Comment: Have you considered an `UPDATE` statement with an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause? It can test and set the `BIT` fields, e.g. using a `CASE` expression in the `SET` clause, and the `OUTPUT` can capture both the _before_ and _after_ values of the columns. While the bit handling may be atomic, it will not prevent any other code in the two functions from overlapping execution. (There is a [boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx#Anchor_0) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one.)

Comment: If the issue is not atomic test-and-set, but preventing larger blocks of code from simultaneous execution, could you add a column to the table? A `Busy` bit (or an `OwnerProcId`) could be `0` (or `NULL`) when the row is available for processing and set to an appropriate value to block other processes. An `UPDATE`/`OUTPUT` allows for atomic test-and-set with the results available to determine whether you "got" the row or it is already owned by another process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either an Application Lock as @Squirrel suggests, or code the transaction to SELECT the row with an [UPDLOCK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table) (which [conflicts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172925(v=sql.110).aspx) with other U locks and X locks), or an XLOCK with conflicts with all other locks.  No isolation level will prevent concurrent reads of the row.

Also note that these locks only prevent reads from other locking transactions.  If you are in SNAPSHOT or READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT consistent reads will not be blocked by transactions holding a U or X lock.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually lock both rows from both tables with a fake update BEFORE selecting data to decide update.

Example :

```
--function A
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TABLE tbl SET A = A, B = B WHERE ID = @id
--logic
SELECT @a = A FROM tbl WHERE WHERE ID = @id
IF @a = 'True' UPDATE tbl SET B = 'False' WHERE ID = @id
--logic end
COMMIT TRANSACTION

--function B
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE TABLE tbl SET A = A, B = B WHERE ID = @id
--logic
SELECT @b = B FROM tbl WHERE WHERE ID = @id
IF @B = 'True' UPDATE tbl SET A = 'False' WHERE ID = @id
--logic end
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```